# How can you speed play mp4 files in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, video-streaming, speech-to-text

I was looking for ways for auto-generate subtitles for mp4 files and I ran across chrome's experimental features of live captioning. However I also want to play the mp4 file at 1.5x speed. How can I do it with chrome or is there any way to achieve live captioning and speed playing?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot speed up a video in chrome using chromes video playback software (This is assuming the address bar shows something like `C:\temp\video.mp4`.) You could try to find a javascript video player that will allow you to do that though. I recommend searching for one on https://github.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use an extension such as this one [Video Speed Controller - Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-speed-controller/nffaoalbilbmmfgbnbgppjihopabppdk).

After installing it, go to the Chrome Extensions page → go to the extension → click "Details", then switch on "Allow access to file URLs"

Edit to add more info: the extension source code is hosted here https://github.com/igrigorik/videospeed. Its function is to control the playback speed of videos played in Chrome. You can search for other similar extension, such as [Video Dominator - Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-dominator/npmegcnbapicebebajligpkjdjjbempo)